# Add a link at the top in ng-admin creation view?

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I am new to ng-admin and also angular(backend-developer).I need to add a link at the top in creation view of all the entities, which on click will download a template for me(via api call).This template is used in creation views to upload a file.

Comment: You'll need to post your code and some details on what you've tried so far. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can customizing the view template help me here?https://ng-admin-book.marmelab.com/doc/Theming.html#customizing-the-view-template-for-a-given-entity